# How to call the implemented hook_profile2_access() function?

Tags: hooks

I'm rather inexperienced in module development, sometimes I have really basic issues: I'd like to grant custom access to user profiles. I think I can do it with the implementation of [hook_profile2_access()](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/profile2/profile2.api.php/function/hook_profile2_access/7) (profile2 and profile2_og_access submodule use such implementations)

I added the `mymodule_profile2_access()` to my module but I don't know how/when it would be called?

Comment: It’ll be called by the entity type manager when access for an entity of that type is requested. But you don’t really need to know that, it just happens, so I wonder if that’s the question you actually want an answer to?

Comment: Well, the question would be why it doesn't seem to work :) if I put this function into *custom_profile_access.module* (just for testing) it should be working, isn't it?  function custom_profile_access_profile2_access($op, $profile = NULL, $account = NULL) { dpm('Hello world'); }

Comment: I don't have time to dig deeper right now, but it's called from profile2.module: `$access = module_invoke_all('profile2_access', $op, $profile, $account);`, in the `profile2_access` function. That would be a good place to start debugging

Comment: Thanks, I've already found that. '$access' returns with arrays containing true/false values, so I'm not sure it will help me. I will check it again nonetheless.

Comment: Have you read the comments? _Only grant access if at least one module granted access and no one denied access._ So even if your hook implementation returns `TRUE`, the result will still be access denied if any other module denies access (i.e. returns `FALSE` from their own implementation of `hook_profile2_access`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was a typical user error: The implemented `mymodule_profile2_access()` function is called only for non-admin users and I checked it with administrator. So simple...